# How to pass data from function one to function two

Tags: php

I want to pass the value of $mine from one to two anyone can help me

```
function one($one_nr) {

        global $db;
        $query = "SELECT one_ward FROM ward WHERE ward_nr =".$db->qstr($one_nr);
        $exe = $db->Execute($query);
        while ($row = $exe->FetchRow()) {
                $get_ward = $row['one_ward'];
        }
        $mine = two($get_ward);

}

function two($mine) {

        var_dump($mine);die;
        global $db;

}
```

Comment: please explain the tags in your question. Also note that your while loop is only setting `$get_ward` to the last item it loops over.

Comment: Assign function to a variable and pass that variable to function "two" as a parameter.

Comment: I want to get the $mine from function one

Comment: But your code does pass the variable to function two. What's the output of the var_dump? And is it different if you place var_dump($get_ward) in function one before calling function two? One thing I've noticed is that you call the function two after the loop, not inside the loop, so you'll only get the last value, not each one.

Comment: if I will var_dump the $get_ward the value is 0 which is correct and if I pass the value to function two it gives null

Comment: gets_awkward ;)
My guess would be a typo in one of the variable names.

Comment: Read about how to define [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function one($one_nr) {
        global $db;
        $query = "SELECT one_ward FROM ward WHERE ward_nr =".$db->qstr($one_nr);
        $exe = $db->Execute($query);
        while ($row = $exe->FetchRow()) {
            $get_ward = $row['one_ward'];
        }
        $mine = two($get_ward);
}
function two($mine) {
        return var_dump($mine);
}
```